# Table border problem

Tags: tables, multicolumn

during my work I've encountered the following problem:
I tried to prepare external border of my table. And it worked fine, to the time I applied `\multicolumn` command to merge two adjacent cells. The name of new merged cell is "Oznaczenia zastosowane w artykule".

Please look at screenshot below.

[image]

We can see that there is blue thin part border color at left and right from the cell "Oznaczenia zastosowane w artykule":

How to improve that and keep that color of external thicker border at both sides (left and right)?

Below is my MWE code:

```
\documentclass[aps,physrev,showkeys,twocolumn,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}


\begin{document}

\onecolumngrid
\newpage
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabular}{ !{\color{red}\VRule[.5mm]} l    l !{\color{green}\VRule[.5mm]}  } \specialrule{.5mm}{2pt}{0cm}
\hfill & \hfill \\[0.25cm]
\multicolumn{2}{|l|} {\hspace{5mm}\textbf{Oznaczenia zastosowane w artykule} }  \\ [4mm]
\hspace{5mm} \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Opis} \\ [4.5mm]
\hspace{5mm} $\mathrm{ a }$ \hspace{3cm} & --~połowa długości [długość] pęknięcia w próbce M(T) [CT]  \\ 
\hspace{5mm} $\mathrm{ BFS }$ & --~oznaczenie pozycji czujnika \\
\hspace{5mm} $\mathrm{ CC }$ & --~zamykanie się pęknięcia  \\ \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

Comment: you specified normal rules `\multicolumn{2}{|l|} ` I guess you wanted `\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{red}\VRule[.5mm]}l!{\color{red}\VRule[.5mm]}} `

Comment: My impression is that you want to consider `tcolorbox` for this task.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, thank you, that has solved my problem :) Thank you also egreg for suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you specified normal rules

```
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}
```

I guess you wanted

```
\multicolumn{2}{!{\color{red}\VRule[.5mm]}l!{\color{red}\VRule[.5mm]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested write your table by using of the `tabularray` package. Its way of writing of multi column cells doesn't overwrite in table preamble defined rules, so your problem cannot be happen:

```
\documentclass[aps,physrev,showkeys,twocolumn,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\onecolumngrid
\newpage
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = {0.5mm,blue}, vline{1,Z} = {0.5mm, red},
             colspec  = {Q[l, mode=math, leftsep=4mm, wd=9em] Q[l]},
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
             row{1-3} = {abovesep=4mm}
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{l}    Oznaczenia zastosowane w artykule     % multicolumn cell    
                &                                                           \\ 
Symbol          &   Opis                                                    \\ 
\mathrm{a}      & -- połowa długości [długość] pęknięcia w próbce M(T) [CT] \\
\mathrm{BFS}    & -- oznaczenie pozycji czujnika                            \\
\mathrm{CC}     & -- zamykanie się pęknięcia                                \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

[image]

In comparison with your MWE, proposed solution ha the following differences:

- first column has left column separation equal 4mm, so you not need to insert horizontal spaces to their cell
- first column is in math node (consequently you not need to write `$`)
- First three row has above vertical space defined in table preamble, so `[5.5mm]˛` after rows terminators are removed
- first two rows are in text mode with `bfseries font

Comment: Thank you, your solution tends to be much elegant and clear!

Comment: @Rejnold, you are welcome.

Comment: @Rejnold, you are welcome. See my similar answer on your previous quartion https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671927/trying-to-use-bigskip-in-the-table-and-cannot-prevent-breaking-table-border-lin/671970#671970. BTW, now you can upvote answers too ...